# In Twilio, how can I log duration of each step in the IVR?

Tags: c#, logging, twilio

Say I am setting up an IVR on Twilio. I need to know how long it takes from the time the customer presses a key or speaks a word to when they are connected accordingly.

How do I instrument the workflow to achieve this goal? I looked at

```
CallResource.Read();
```

but didn't see logging/instrumentation information

Comment: I think we'd need more info about what your application is doing to help.  There are a multitude of things that could be timed and I'm not sure what you mean by "connected".

Comment: Here's one way to describe what I am attempting: load this URL:
`https://networktest.twilio.com/` and you will see a log like this:
`[‎10‎:‎25‎:‎30‎ ‎PM] Test "Test Call" started...`
I need a similar log at method call level

Comment: The code I am trying to instrument is a Twilio sample that I need to augment with instrumentation/logging so that I can compute how long each step takes:

 ` // POST: IVR/Welcome`
` [HttpPost] public `
`TwiMLResult Welcome() { var response = new VoiceResponse(); var gather = new Gather(action: Url.ActionUri("Show", "Menu"), numDigits: 1); gather.Say("Thank you for calling the E.T. Phone Home Service. Press 1 for directions, press 2 to make a call."); response.Append(gather); return TwiML(response); } `

Comment: @DevinRader would you please pick something you are familiar with and show me how you time it? That will help. I mostly want to find out if there is support in Twilio for measurements or not. I have not found any documentation on this topic